Error when trying to fetch time-series data using a specific time range in my GridDB query
I am trying to fetch data from a TimeSeries container within a specific time range. The code runs, but I am getting an error that says "Syntax Error near 'NOW'". Here's the Python code I'm using:
from griddb_python import *

factory = StoreFactory.get_instance()
gridstore = factory.get_store(host="127.0.0.1", port=10001, cluster_name="myCluster", username="admin", password="admin")

# Access the container
container = gridstore.get_container("sensor_data")

# Query data within the last 24 hours
query = container.query("SELECT * WHERE timestamp > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY'")
rs = query.fetch()

while rs.has_next():
    data = rs.next()
    print(data)


I need help understanding why the NOW() function isn't working and what I can do to fetch data for the past 24 hours. Is there something wrong with my query syntax?

I think the error is because griddb do not support the NOW() function. In my opinion you should calculate the current timestamp and then pass the same as part of your query. You should use datetime function of python to calculate the current time and then subtract 24 hours from your result. I hope this will help.
